# Bots and scripts

Tags: google, javascript, googlebot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will AJAX-fetched material be invisible to search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8429/will-ajax-fetched-material-be-invisible-to-search-engines)

Can bots understand what's going on in javascript or vbscript? Most of the social networking modules and ad codes consist of just a js file which appends an iframe (google+ button, facebook like button, facebook likebox, google ads etc). Do bots understand that there are iframes involved in the site? Do bots run javascript and check the result? Or at least try to understand what's going in that js?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for most bots is no, they don't understand javascript. However according to the answer to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript) Google is experimenting with looking at javascript.